# Ubuntu Server with static VPN IP

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, remote-access, pptp, static-ip

I have a remote ubuntu server that connects to our company's VPN.  Every time it connects it gets a dynamic IP.  I need it to be static.  The VPN assigning dynamic IPs is fine for all our road warriors, but not for the remote ubuntu server.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for setting up pptp with static IP?

Thank you!

Or, on the otherside, is there a way to tell "Routing and Remote Access" "Hey, when this user, mac address, or remote IP connects, give it this internal IP"

**`UPDATE`**
I found the following [post](http://www.howtonetworking.com/VPN/vpnip1.htm) that mentions setting up a remote access policy.  I've tried adding the condition "NAS-IP-Address matches xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" put that as the first rule, but it didn't work.  I also tried the "Calling-Station-Id", but that didn't work either.  I think here lies the key.  My only two other rules are the defualt, "connections to MS RRAS" and "Connections to other access servers".  Both of which are set to order 2 & 3 respectively.

Comment: What is the VPN endpoint/server?

Comment: Windows 2003 server

Comment: Are you using DHCP to issue your IP's for the VPN, or just have a static pool allocated in RRAS?

Comment: As I remember, when I first set it up I used DHCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](http://www.howtonetworking.com/VPN/vpnip1.htm) I found the key.
You have to setup a policy for "calling-station-id" and set it to the remote vpn clients IP. then set that up as the first rule.

This may not be ideal, but it does work.